# Symfony 5 Object not found on all pages except the homepage

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm trying to install a fresh Symfony 5 project. The instiallation was successful and I was able to see "Welcome to Symfony 5.3.6" page.
Then I created a controller and a route for it, just like in the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html)

1. config/routes.yaml

```
app_lucky_number:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

2. src/Controller/LuckyController.php

```
    public function number(): Response
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
```

But I'm getting `Object not found!` error on `/lucky/number` page. I tried to put that action on `/` index page, and I was able to see the correct output. But it doesn't work if I put that action on any other page, only `/` works.
What am I missing?

I'm using XAMPP server with PHP 7.4.1.

Comment: Does bin/console debug:router show the expected routes?

Comment: Have you configured your web server somehow? For example for apache you can do `composer require symfony/apache-pack`

Comment: You must configure your server (XAMPP) or use something like the Symfony CLI: https://symfony.com/download

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "Object not found"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Flash's comment now I know what I have missed -
`composer require symfony/apache-pack` fixed the issue.

Comment: Also important thing to note - it may work even when "just" uninstalled. One needs both - turn on the apache mod rewrite && this bundle.